# в чем смысл "where"? если и без него выведет "Сегодня среда". для чего вообще where нужен?

Tags: swift

```
 var today = 3
switch today {
case 1...4 where today == 3:
    print("Сегодня среда")
case 1...5:
    print("Сегодня будний день")
case 6...7:
    print("Сегодня выходной")
default:
    print("Неправильный номер недели")
}
```

Comment: *если и без него выведет "Сегодня среда"* - в любой будний день

Comment: Это как бы ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: @iosDeveloper измените значение переменной `today` и попробуйте без `where`

Comment: Очень неудачный пример. Если `today` всегда равен 3, то весь этот код не нужен. Если Ваш вопрос о глобальном значении `where`, а не о поведении конкретного нода, то этот момент нужно поподробнее расписать в тексте вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл `where` в уточнении условия и в отличие от `++` и `--`, это очень нужная вещь. Ваш пример просто не требует подобного уточнения, так как он покрывает это условие. Хоть и странное.
Возьмем, к примеру, телефоны:

```
enum Phone {
    case iPhone(modelName: String)
    case samsung(model: String)
}

let phones: [Phone] = [.iPhone(modelName: "7S Plus"), 
                       .iPhone(modelName: "SE"), 
                       .samsung(model: "Note 7"), 
                       .samsung(model: "Не лопата")]
```

Пусть будут 2 основные ТМ: iPhone и Samsung. Модели - простая строка. И теперь нам нужно выбрать маленькие телефоны:

```
for phone in phones {
    switch phone {
    case .iPhone(let modelName) where ["SE", "5S"].contains(modelName):
        print("Маленький телефон")
    case .samsung(let model) where model == "Не лопата":
        print("Не флагман")
    default:
        print("Лопата")
    }
}
```

И теперь все устройства, которые не прописаны в `where`, попадут в категорию "Лопата".

Answer (score 0):

*Swift* здесь не главное. Код, который Вы привели, можно переписать:

```
switch today {
case 3:
    print("Сегодня среда")
case 1...5:
    print("Сегодня будний день")
case 6...7:
    print("Сегодня выходной")
default:
    print("Неправильный номер недели")
}
```

*Update*

Мы с Вами, кажется, взяли неверную ноту с самого начала.

Я хотел сказать в моем первом комментарии, что Ваша фраза

> и без `where` выведет `"Сегодня среда"`

будет верна для любого значения `today` от одного до пяти. Но среда-то соответствует только значению `3`.

Comment: не сильно код поменялся. Я корень хочу понять языка этого. Раньше там был оператор инкремента и декремента а++ и а-- но их удалили создатели Свифта за ненадобностью и сбивания с толку когда есть а += и а -=. Так если c where и без него одно и тоже, значит удаление ждет? Прошу вас, если вы это ясно понимаете, будьте любезны объясните начинающему)

Comment: @iosDeveloper Какое удаление? При чем тут `++` и `--`? Пожалуйста, постарайтесь сформулировать вопрос с учетом того, что мне неизвестны Ваши мысли :).

Comment: Это я как пример привел и еще раз объясню вам тогда:) Если вы говорите что и без where можно, то я говорил о том, что не ждет ли его судьба удаления из языка вообще? как тех примеров которые я привел.